# Use Javascript/jQuery in CSS to make border-right mirror border-bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First off, let me apologize for my ignorance. I'm a new developer just trying to learn the ropes, and I've come across a roadblock here. I'll briefly explain my WP setup:

Section div > Section class > section::before and ::after pseudo elements.

I have inherit for my pseudo, so when I use my front end editor to change the border color size, etc. the pseudo follows. However, it only affects the same border as its parent. What I'm trying to do is have the border-right of the ::after pseudo use the same value that is entered as its border-bottom value.

Hopefully that makes sense. I wish I had the words to more articulately explain what I'm going after. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks!

```
    /* Triangles */
.ss-style-triangles::before,
.ss-style-triangles::after {
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border: inherit;
}

.ss-style-triangles::before {
    display: none;
  border: inherit;
  top: -25px;
    background: inherit;
  z-index: -9999;
}

.ss-style-triangles::after {
  border-right: solid 1px;
  bottom: -26px;
    z-index: 0;
    background: inherit;
}
```

Comment: So here's the skinny: On my Wordpress, I want to create custom separators, so it's not just a boring line separating each section. This basically makes a small square, rotates it, and applies the inherited bottom border (making it a triangle). The catch is, cause it's a square, the bottom border is the left of the triangle and the right border is left out. I need to use some type of code to analyze what that pseudo (or parent's) border-bottom value is, and apply it to the border-right property of that pseudo. Or apply it to the class, and have the pseudo inherit it. If that makes sense.

Comment: could you show the snapshot

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ba0i4b

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a snippet in the question? That would make it much more easier for us to see what is wrong. You can edit your question and use the `<>` button to insert a snippet. Thanks.

Comment: I honestly wish I were smart enough to do that. :-/

I can't seem to make the divs touch, so it doesn't give the desired effect. Go easy on me! In a year, I'll be a pro. I promise! :D

I tried (and failed) to make a codepen. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my own code experiment, here it is

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    padding: 50px;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10% 0 0;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

#content h1, #content h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
}

#content h1 {
    font-size: 65px;
}

#content h3 {
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.block-left {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c00000;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.block-right {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}

.arrow-down {
    border-top: 20px solid #E8E8E8;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    margin: -1px auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.arrow-down::before,
.arrow-down::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 28px;
}

.arrow-down::before {
    background-color: #c00000;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-top: -23px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.arrow-down::after {
    background-color: #000000;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-top: -28px;
    margin-left: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <h1>What We Offer</h1>
    <h3>We offer many classes to help you build your skills, or to just have fun.</h3>
    <h3>Check out the list below!</h3>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="block-left"></div>
    <div class="block-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

Comment: I should've switch the dang code. Ugh. Apologies. I want the color and size of the border-right to match the rest. Right now it's black. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for helping me as well!

Comment: Man -- I am *SO* sorry. I am doing a *terrible* job of describing myself. Hopefully I can clarify myself finally. hahaha

By border-right, I'm referring to the right part of the triangle -- the right border of the rotated square. I'd like it (in this case) to all be red. Mea culpa. :(

Is this setup to be modular? What I mean is, the front-end of the editor (in my case, X theme) I can vary the color and width with a slider. All of it (sans the right border of the triangle) change. I need the border to match the rest. If that makes sense.

Comment: could you take a snapshot of the layout you wanted to be

Comment: I can't post code here. I just need the *entire* border red, instead of half red and half black.

Comment: the entire border of the content and the triangle?

Comment: Just the bottom of the content and the bottom and right of the square (the left and right of the triangle)

It's being used as a 'separator' from one band of content and the next.